# Smali:All register args must fit in 4 bits error

Tags: android, smali

when i used smali to dex my mod file, I got this error:

> patch\android\view\Choreographer.smali[1392,4] All register args must
>   fit in 4 bits

I located to line 1392 and found:

```
invoke-direct {p0, p1, p2, p3}, Landroid/view/Choreographer;->MyFunc(JI)V 
invoke-static {}, Ljava/lang/System;->nanoTime()J  (line 1392)

move-result-wide v11
```

Does somebody know how do i fix it? I have read this post http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=733275, but it didn't help, because this line 
did not use any register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the first line

```
invoke-direct {p0, p1, p2, p3}, Landroid/view/Choreographer;->MyFunc(JI)V
```

You can only use registers v0-v15, because the numeric register index must fit within 4 bits. The method apparently has a large number of registers, so that at least p3 maps to a register that is higher than v15.

Fortunately, the registers are contiguous, so the fix is simple

```
invoke-direct/range {p0 .. p3}, Landroid/view/Choreographer;->MyFunc(JI)V
```

The /range variant accepts a contiguous range of registers, and can address up to v65535.

Comment: If you're not clear on how the p* registers map onto the v* registers, you can find more info at https://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/Registers

Comment: Thank you JesusFreke, it is indeed  what you hava said that the method has more than 16 registers(22). Now I hava fixed the problem by your provided mean. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is address-range for invoke-static/range? I am trying to use a static method and registers > v15

Comment: @alchemist - the docs are your friend: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html. "argument word count (8 bits)" and "first argument register (16 bits)"

Comment: @JesusFreke Thanks for the reply. But looks like even this is not working for me. I did not get the error saying "use registers v0-v15", but the apk built crashed on phone with error : Compile time verification failed. Please help.

Comment: Background: We have a code, in which we are trying to insert some debug logs. We need two extra registers per method to enable these logs. 

What we have tried so far: Increasing registers - Did not work as registers > v15 are breaking the code.
Moving v0 and v1 register values to some high value registers like v250 or something, then use v0-v1 and reassign values back from vTMP to v0-v1 - No errors but app crashes with Compile time verification error.

Comment: @alchemist Feel free to post an actual question :)

Comment: @JesusFreke there you go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501985/increase-use-modify-smali-registers